# Convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$, $a_n = f(\frac 1 n)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I need help with this problem:

> Let $f$ be a continous function over an interval that contains $0$. Let $a_n = f(\frac1 n)$ (for n large enough).
>
> 1. Show that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$ converges, then $f(0)=0$.
> 2. Show that if $f'(0)$ exists and $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$ converges, then $f'(0)=0$.
> 3. Show that if $f''(0)$ exists and $f(0)=f'(0)=0$, then $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$ converges.
> 4. Suppose that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$ converges. Should $f'(0)$ exist?
> 5. Suppose that $f(0)=f'(0)=0$. Should $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$ converge?

I don't know how to solve this. I solved the first one, saying that if $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$ converges that tells me that $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =0$. Beacuse of that, I can say that $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(\frac 1 n) = k$, since $f$ is continous on $0$, that means that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(\frac 1 n) = f(0)$ thus $f(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = \lim_{n\to 0} f(\frac 1 n) = 0$.

How can I solve this? Please explain it to me.

Comment: You are right. For convergence you need $\lim f(1/n)=0$ but since $f$ is continuous at zero, the limit has to coincide with the value of the function, that is, $f(0)=0$.

Comment: So, because $\lim_{n\to\infty} f(\frac 1 n) = x$, right? but how do I prove that it equals $0$? Can I say that the hypothesis was that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \ a_n$ converges?

Comment: Series convergent implies $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}a_n=0$, therefore $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(1/n)=0$. By continuity, we know that $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=f(0)$ and by uniqueness of the limit (along any sequence converging zero) you have  $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f(1/n)=0$. Therefore, $f(0)=0$.

Comment: Yes. The statement assumes that your series is convergent.

Comment: Ok, thanks! And what about the others?

Answer (score 2):

Part (1) was answered in the comments.

---

For (2), suppose that $f'(0)=t> 0$.  Then $$t=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(1/n)-f(0)}{1/n}=\lim_{n\to \infty}nf(1/n)=\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n$$

Because $\lim_{n\to\infty} na_n=t$, there must be some $N$ such that for all $n>N$, $|na_n-t|<\frac{t}{2}$.  Hence, for such $n$, $-\frac{t}{2}<na_n-t<\frac{t}{2}$.  Adding $t$ throughout, we get $\frac{t}{2}<na_n$.

Hence, there is some $N$, such that for all $n>N$, we must have $na_n>\frac{t}{2}$, and hence $a_n>\frac{1}{n}\frac{t}{2}$.  This gives $$\sum_{n>N} a_n \ge \sum_{n>N}\frac{1}{n}\frac{t}{2}=\frac{t}{2}\sum_{n>N} \frac{1}{n}$$
But the harmonic series diverges, so the original series diverges.  Contradiction.

Note: if $t<0$, the proof is similar, except now $\sum a_n$ goes to $-\infty$.

---

For (3)-(5), you really should ask these as separate questions.

Comment: I didn't understand the last part. I understood how you got $\lim_{n\to\infty} \ na_n$. Then n>N is the convergence definition, right? I don't get why $na_n > \frac{t 2}.

Comment: Adding more explanation by request.

Comment: Thanks, I get it know. The summation $\sum_{n>N} a_n$ goes from $n>N$ to $\infty$?

Comment: Correct, $\sum_{n>N}$ means $\sum_{n=N+1}^\infty$.